# Best practice of passing 3rd party api response codes

Tags: java, api, architecture

Let's say I have endpoint returning weather from 3rd party api:

```
@Path("/weather")
Response getWeather(double latitude, double longtitude) {
    Weather weather = weatherService.getWeather(latitude, longtitude);
    return wrapWithHttpOK(weather);
}
```

It works perfectly fine when the 3rd party weather api always successfully returns weather. But sometimes it can return:

- 400 Bad request for invalid latitude, longtitude
- 404 Not found for locations thst this api does not cover
- 500 Internal server error

What is the best way to organize my code to return 400 and 404 from my api and handle 500 with 503 Service not available? Is it good idea to throw custom exceptions for this cases? Or should i make  `weatherService` return some kind of status alongside with entity? Is there a library for this purpose?

Would also be nice to know if there is any literature or articles covering such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we throw exceptions rather than returning error codes.

Exceptions force the client of your code (consumer of your API) to handle the exception. For example a 4xx HTTP code could indicate faulty code.
Usually the caller expects and depends on the result of your API. When your API fails to satisfy this expectation it must communicate this exceptional situation or object state by throwing an exception.

Error codes are used accross application boundaries, like when consuming a Rest service. The remote service can't throw an exception in the client application. It can only send you a response containing a special code or a special response object to indicate an error.
As soon as such an error enters your application/library, you must convert it to a meaningful exception which means a meaningful exception name and a meaningful exception message. Consider to extend `Exception` if there is no meaningful standard exception available.

A good exception name and message is far more convenient to handle than a code.
While the name and the message can be directly consumed, a code must *always* be decoded e.g., by using an error code table.

Since exceptions are expensive in terms of performance, you should *always* avoid them in the first place. It is primarily the responsibility of the caller to ensure that the arguments passed to the API are valid.
Then have your API to validate the parameters before using them (e.g., with the "expensive" Rest service - maybe you don't whant to waste bandwidth by sending invalid requests) and throw ArgumentException if they are invalid.
In addition you can design your API in way that it semantically communicates that a failing operation is possible by adding an alternative the Try-Do pattern implementation:

```
public boolean tryGetWeather(Response response) {

  // Call Rest API

  if (restApiResponseCode != 200) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // Set the result parameter 
  response.Weather = weatherData;
  return true;
}
```

The `tryxxx` implies that the operation is expected to fail and that the ccaller should observe and handle the result. This is usually used for non-critical operations (e.g., value conversions - like testing if a string is a number).

When using the Try-Do pattern, a good API always offers a breaking default version in case the consumer wants the application to halt on error (because it may indicate faulty code):

```
public Response getWeather(double latitude, double longtitude) {

 // Validate parameters before using them.
 // Longitudes range from -180 to 180.
 if (longitude > 180 || longitude < -180)
   throw new InvalidLongitudeException();

  // Call Rest API

  if (restApiResponseCode != 200) {
    throw new WeatherServiceException();
  }
  
  // Set the result parameter 
  response.Weather = weatherData;
  return response;
}
```

Since you would always expect a weather result from a weather API, the Try-Do pattern is not suitable for your scenario. You should convert the error codes to exceptions.

Wether you use the Try-Do pattern for less critical operations or not: always throw exceptions rather than returning error codes.